# Does Hadoop Copy Data from Data Sources it Connect to?

Tags: hadoop

When Hadoop is connected to some data sources such as MongoDB or MySQL, does it copy the data from these sources into the Hadoop file system or it simply works with that remote data?  My expectation is that Hadoop would copy such data into its own file system; otherwise, in my view all the advantages of Hadoop which rests in breaking the data in blocks which reside on different data node would disappear.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MR jobs always take their data from the HDFS.
for example if you have some MySQL table which holds some metadata that is essential for your MR job, you will need this data stored in the HDFS, either serialized or structured (tsv for example).
Then you can import these files using `DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles` and use the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

The common workflow in such cases is to use Apache Sqoop to start an efficient and parallel copy operation from the Database source to the HDFS directory of choice (can also copy to a Hive table instead, for example).

While the copy operation executes, data that is being written to HDFS is distributed in parallel to the HDFS Datanodes. Once done, it is ready to be consumed by Hadoop engines such as Mapreduce, Hive, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No in case you have DB as input source, hadoop will not copy data into hdfs .